# Hugginface Transformers: how to load for local disk?

Tags: model, load, huggingface-transformers, openai-whisper, vtt

I'm trying to load the model after the training as done and its saved the training to a local storage. after the training done these are the files that created:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doBbC.png)

I'm trying to load it like this but its not working for me:

````
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(r"C:\pythonProject\pythonProjectHF\hebrew_speech_kan_model")

model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("sanchit-gandhi/whisper-small-hi")```
````